# opencv: getPixel() not reflecting drawRectangle()

Tags: python, simplecv

When I draw a red square into an image, I expect the pixels in that square to be 'red'.  However, they turn out to be black...

```
>>> from SimpleCV import Image,Color
>>> Color.RED
(255, 0, 0)
>>> i=Image((100,100))  
>>> i.drawRectangle(10,10,20,20,Color.RED,0,255) 
>>> i.getPixel(15,15)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @karlphillip: right you are.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.... Apparently, the `drawRectangle` call draws onto the current drawing layer.  After a call to `applyLayers()`, the pixel was more as expected.

```
>>> from SimpleCV import Image,Color
>>> Color.RED
(255, 0, 0)
>>> i=Image((100,100))  
>>> i.drawRectangle(10,10,20,20,Color.RED,0,255) 
>>> i.getPixel(15,15)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Here goes:

```
>>> i=i.applyLayers() 
>>> i.getPixel(15,15)
(254.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: It's funny how sometimes we find the answers ourselves right after asking a question, isn't it? I've been known to do that as well.